# How to find part of substring String

Tags: python, string

I am trying to get a part of an equation (which is just a string).
So what i want is a kind of: `string.find('s(n-',*,')')`. So that I will find a part that is `s(n-5)` or `s(n-20)`

I already tried some stuff with fnmatch but that did not work out well

```
end = equation.find(")") + 1
for letter in equation:
    if letter not in operators and letter not in str_ints:
        start = start + 1
    else:
        break

function_bit = equation[start: end]
```

So I want to extract every bit of s(n-*) in a long string

So I got a string like: "(9/2)*s(n-2)+(3/2)*s(n-3)-5*s(n-4)-3*s(n-5)+(n-5)**2-3*(n-5)+7"

and that needs to be cut upp in all the s(n-*)pieces

Comment: `import re` and `arr = re.findall(r's\(n-\d+\)', s)` where s is the string you're matching against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend regex for this:

```
In [6]: import re

In [7]: s = "s(n-5) somethingelse s(n-20)"

In [9]: res = re.findall("s\(n-\d+\)", s)

In [10]: for r in res:
    ...:     print(r)
    ...:
s(n-5)
s(n-20)
```

You can find the regex documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html). Regex is very powerful once you understand it, so it's worth investing some time learning it IMO.